# How to remap keys / add shortcuts on Mac OS X, without 3rd party software?

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm trying to do simple things like map the sleep shortcut to <kbd>F7</kbd>, monitor sleep shortcut to <kbd>F8</kbd> etc

I've checked out Ukelele, yet couldn't determine whether it's able produce key combinations / whether the layout syntax is flexible enough

I don't want to use Karabiner, as I don't want to modify the system If I don't have to (Although Karabiner is open source, I'm still weary of possible technical glitches and they do seem to happen, as some people reported with other remappers)

I've also tested the DefaultKeyBinding.dict, but it seems to be for in-app key bindings as far as I can see, couldn't achieve what I wanted

It's a shame that Mac OS X doesn't allow this natively, am I missing a simpler solution?